# BinPacker giving TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run a binpacking algorithm from github but I keep getting the above mentioned error. Here is the code parts that the error refer to:

```
model = BRKGA(inputs, num_generations = 100, num_individuals=70, num_elites = 10, num_mutants = 7, eliteCProb = 0.7)



model.fit(patient = 15,verbose = True)
f partition(self, population, fitness_list):
        sorted_indexs = np.argsort(fitness_list)
        return population[sorted_indexs[:self.num_elites]], population[sorted_indexs[self.num_elites:]], fitness_list[sorted_indexs[:self.num_elites]]



elites, non_elites, elite_fitness_list = self.partition(population, fitness_list)
```

The error is shown in the image. If its not possible to see the issue from this information I can add more.[image]